# Life-cycle difference between docker run and docker start

Tags: docker

I have a fundamental question about container life cycle.

For example I run the following command

> Create new ubuntu container and run the bash command

```
docker run -it ubuntu bash
```

> In the container's bash

```
exit
```

> The new container will be in state EXITED

```
docker ps -a
```

> Then I use docker start to restart the container

```
docker start xxxx(container name)
docker exec -it xxxx(container name) /bin/bash
```

> In the restarted container's bash

```
exit
```

> The restarted container is still running

```
docker ps -a
```

May I know the reason behind for this behavior? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `docker run` command:

```
docker run -it ubuntu bash
```

the container is started with the execution of the `bash` command, so when you `exit` from the `bash`, the container also exits as `bash` is the main process running inside the container.

However with the `docker exec` command:

```
docker exec -it xxxx(container name) /bin/bash
```

the container is already running the command defined by the [`CMD`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd)/[`ENTRYPOINT`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint) and `bash` is the command executed as a separate process. So, `exit`ing from `bash` after `docker start` exits the `bash` process and the main process is still continued.